# Output variables containing numbers in a loop

Tags: julia

I have the following variables

```
a1 = 2
a2 = 20
a3 = 200
```

Is it possible to output them while looping over the integers 1, 2 and 3? Something like the following although it doesn't work as intended

```
for i in [1,2,3]
    println(:"a$i") # doesn't work
    println("a" * string(i)) # doesn't work
end
```

Comment: Although noted in answers, it is suggested to avoid this, just for general info: `getfield(Main, Symbol("a$i"))` would return the value for a given `i` (for the REPL, in Module code, replace `Main` with module name).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a dictionary, but this looks like a job for arrays:

```
julia> a = [2, 20, 200]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
   2
  20
 200

julia> for i in eachindex(a)
           println(a[i])
       end
2
20
200
```

It is typical for beginner programmers to try to create and access variables dynamically. It is *possible* to do, but you should not do it. It makes code fragile and hard to read, and also slow and bug-prone. This is why *data structures* exist, that allow you to collect data in a structured way.

And alternative to arrays, is to use a tuple, `a = (2, 20, 200)`. It works much the same way, except you cannot change a tuple after it has been created.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [dictionary](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Dictionaries) to store the variables:

```
julia> d = Dict("a1"=>2, "a2"=>20, "a3"=>200)
Dict{String, Int64} with 3 entries:
  "a3" => 200
  "a2" => 20
  "a1" => 2

julia> for i in [1, 2, 3]
           println(d["a$i"])
       end
2
20
200
```

Comment: It's not possible without a dictionary?

Comment: It may be possible, but it is most likely a hacky solution based on experience from other languages.